# Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object to load model in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am getting a error in Magento in load store module.

```
/** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Store */
$storeCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
    ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG))
    ->setLoadDefault(true);
```

And I am getting.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php on line 20379

When I am trying to call module it return false.

```
var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel('core/store')));exit;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I'd guess that there is something wrong with `('core/store')` are you sure that is correct, with capitalisation etc?

Comment: @James, Yes, Its correct. That was working but after some days without any modification its showing this error.